# Use PHP's file_get_contents with a file on users local system?

Tags: php, file-upload

Is there a way to use PHP's file_get_contents() function on a file that a user is trying to upload from their computer through the browser with a form?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Directly - no. This is not how PHP works - it runs entirely on server side.

After uploading - definitely! You can load the file using the `tmpfile` element in the `$_FILES` array. See [Handling File Uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) for more info.

Comment: OK,any ideas how to do this?  I have a class that uploads a video to youtube, right now i pass it the file path of the video and it uploads it using file_get_contents(), I have to change it so I can select a video from my PC instead though

Answer (score 1):

Only way to communicate with the users filesystem is through the upload filesystem. There is of course a reason that you cannot just access files from a clients computer, this would imply enormous security issues.

If you really need to do something with files on a users computer, look into Adobe Flash, Silverlight, Java or write a plugin.